# TFS File Changed Notifications in future branches

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We've got TFS email alerts set up when certain files are changed. In the future, many of these files will likely have "copies" via branching.  Other than manually creating additional alerts each time a branch is created, can anyone offer some strategies for this scenario?  Or simply strategies to make sure we're covered in case a branch is created and we forget to create these alerts.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box feature for this, you can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

However, if the name of the files is unique，you can create an email alert just with "File Name = filename.extension" and "Folder Path Contains XXX". This will track the change for the file in the specified folders/branches.